# Best solution for retrieve and manage phone contacts on server side?

Tags: java, neo4j, relational-database, android-contacts, graph-databases

I want to create an android application which retrieve and save phone contacts on server side, then the server-side application have to manage them and find the contacts which have installed the same android application on their phones.

I need some advice for choosing technology stack? Do you know any similar solution?
Which kind of database you recommend? Are graph-based databases (like Neo4J) any good or I just use relational databases?Performance and scalability considerations are very important to me.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is an open one, and will fit into a discussion on `graph db` vs `rdbms`. SO is not make for that. Please refine your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you build a prototype. Begin with a server side application with a relational database. Use a DAO layer so you can change the db implemantation later if needed.

Initially, I suppose your requirements are just functionality. So go for it and build something that works. Later on, you can continue with performance and scalability considerations, but when you have reached that point you will have much more experience in what you are trying to built and alternatives you could follow.

Now the modile (Android) app is a different story. I suggest you build an app that sends and retrieves data(contacts) to and from the server to begin with.

Finally, you could download some similar apps and try to replicate their UI.

Comment: Thank you, but i don't have time for try-and-error approaches. Unfortunately I didn't find any useful resources on the web.The performance and scalability are the key points of my decision and I have to decide between graph-base and relational databases now.

Comment: If it's easy for you to go with a graph-base db then go for it. But if you don't have time, then do not try to reinvent the wheel. Play on your strenths and build something fast. Then continue on upgrading it with new mechanisms. That is the purpose of layers. To promope modifiability. Up to you dude.